# How to go about an Ico creation job

Tags: erc-20, ico

Am a developer and of late most projects being posted are on ico creation an example,

> 1.Need someone to create a complete ICO website including ERC 20 token creation via Ethereum.
>
> 2.Need ICO, ucoincash script, lending and staking

Looks simple enough, but the problem is there is very few documentation on the subject. Am trying to learn the ethereum but need guidance on how to go about this jobs.

I do not have a clue on how to handle this jobs any help on how to tackle them will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi there. This is a very broad question, so will probably be flagged as such. I'd recommend going through the tutorials on the "official" website, which include one on tokens. https://ethereum.org/token Read around the subject more, either on this site, or on Reddit, and when you have more focused/specific problems, this would be the place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a few weeks ahead of you,  the code is out there for an ICO smart contract, there are a few tutorials that walk you through deploying the smart contract to the blockchain.  Once you can and know how to do this, having an ICO website that uses Web3.js to interact with the deployed contract is the easy part and there are plenty of tutorials out there for using web3.js

I just googled and the first result I looked at is a nice step by step walkthrough
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/99/Interacting-with-a-Smart-Contract-through-Web3.js-(Tutorial)